# Passing Excel column data to Power Bi desktop table as a filter data

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerbi, amazon-redshift

I have to pass excel column values to powerBi redshift data as a filter.I have 4 tables from redshift database from which I am taking few columns. Through Excel which is in teams SharePoint I need to pass the column values to power BI so that I can get the data corresponding to the Excel data from redshift database. Order number is the common column in Excel and redshift..so I have to take the data for the order which are there in excel

How can I achieve this

Comment: You can then load the filtered data into Power BI. Here are some resources that might help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-report-add-filter?tabs=powerbi-desktop